# Insert into another table after fetching latest date and and performing an inner join

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, sql-insert

I have a table called "Member_Details" which has multiple records for each member_ID. For Example,

[image]

I have another table called "BMI_Data" that looks like the following.

[image]

The goal is to fetch the names of those members whose "BMI" in "Member_Details" is less than the "target_BMI" in "BMI_Data" table and insert it into a new table called "results" with "Member_ID, First_Name and BMI" as its schema. 
Also, one consideration is to fetch the latest data available in the "Member_Details" for each member (based on date) and then do the comparison

The result for the above scenario would be something like this.

[image]

I tried using the following query

```
INSERT INTO results_table (Member_ID, First_Name, BMI)  
select  c.Member_ID, First_Name, BMI 
from 
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Member_ID ORDER BY Date desc) 
AS ROWNUM FROM Member_Details) x  
JOIN 
BMI_Data c ON x.Member_ID = c.Member_ID 
where 
x.BMI < c.Target_BMI
```

The above query doesn't fetch the latest date and simply loads all records in which member BMI is less than target_BMI.

Please help !

Comment: Does the select itself return the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate query might be

```
INSERT INTO results_table (Member_ID, First_Name, BMI)
select md2.member_ID, md2.First_Name, md2.BMI
from BMI_Data bd
inner join (select distinct md.member_ID ,md.First_Name ,(select top 1 BMI from Member_Details where member_ID = md.member_ID order by Date desc) BMI from Member_Details md) md2 on md2.member_ID = bd.member_ID
where md2.BMI < bd.Target_BMI
```

Answer (score 1):

First you haven't specify the condition after `row_numbers` defined

```
INSERT INTO results_table (Member_ID, First_Name, BMI)  
select  c.Member_ID, First_Name, BMI 
from  (SELECT *, 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Member_ID ORDER BY Date desc)  AS ROWNUM 
       FROM Member_Details
      ) x  JOIN BMI_Data c 
                ON x.Member_ID = c.Member_ID 
where x.ROWNUM = 1 and x.BMI < c.Target_BMI;
```

Comment: You are awesome ! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to note - there is no such date as '31-April-2018'! You might meant '1-May-2018'

In any case - it is important to make sure that when you are ordering by Date you first cast it to data type of DATE otherwise ordering is not correct. Below makes this ordering proper and in addition proposes alternative way by using ARRAY_AGG() with ORDER BY and LIMIT 1

```
#standardSQL
INSERT INTO results_table (Member_ID, First_Name, BMI)
SELECT * EXCEPT(Target_BMI)
FROM (
  SELECT Member_ID, First_Name, 
    ARRAY_AGG(BMI ORDER BY PARSE_DATE('%d-%B-%Y', Date) DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] BMI
  FROM `project.dataset.member_details`
  GROUP BY Member_ID, First_Name
) d
JOIN `project.dataset.bmi_data` t
USING(Member_ID)
WHERE BMI < Target_BMI
```